# Android Google Maps is not showing circle drawed

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to draw circle on marker position by using this code

```
 private void setMarker() {
        if (nMarker != null) {
            removeMapContents();
        }
        Address nAddress = CommonObjects.getCurrentMyPlace().getPlaceAddress();
        setPlaceContents();
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(nAddress.getLatitude(), nAddress.getLongitude());
        nCircle = drawCircle(ll);
        MarkerOptions nMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .title(nAddress.getLocality())
                .position(ll)
                .draggable(true);
        nMarker = CommonObjects.getMap().addMarker(nMarkerOptions);
    }

private Circle drawCircle(LatLng ll) {
    CircleOptions nCircleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(ll)
            .radius(Constants.DEFAULT_RADIUS_VALUE)
            .fillColor(Color.BLACK)
            .strokeColor(Constants.DEFAULT_RADIUS_STROKE_COLOR)
            .strokeWidth(Constants.DEFAULT_RADIUS_STROKE_WIDTH);    
    return CommonObjects.getMap().addCircle(nCircleOptions);
}
```

here the values are taken from this class

```
    public class Constants {
        public static final int GPS_ERRORIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
        public static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 5;
        public static final int DEFAULT_RADIUS_INDEX = 5;
        public static final String DEFAULT_RADIUS = "Radius 500 Meters";
        public static final int DEFAULT_SPINNER_INDEX = 0;
        public static final String DEFAULT_CONTACT = "Select Contact";
        public static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Enter Message";
        public static final boolean DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_CHECK = false;
        public static final double DEFAULT_RADIUS_VALUE = 1000;
        public static final int DEFAULT_RADIUS_STROKE_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
        public static final int DEFAULT_RADIUS_FILL_COLOR = 0x330000FF;
        public static final float DEFAULT_RADIUS_STROKE_WIDTH = 3;

    }
```

the code runs successfully and no errors are occurring but also no circle is drawn on marker position.

Comment: I think you DEFAULT_RADIUS_INDEX value is to small try to set 100 and check what happen.

Comment: No that's not working and also 1000 is very great value then 100 so radius should be drawn necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem My DEFAULT_ZOOM value was to small so i increased it it from 5 to 14 and the circle now displayed of DEFAULT_RADIUS value with 500 meters.